# Using multiple threads for faster execution

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, algorithm

**Approximate program behavior:**
I have a map image with data associated with the map indicated by RGB index. The data has been populated into an MS Access database. I imported the information in the database into my program as an array and sorted them to go in the order I want the program to run.

I want the program to find the nearest pixel that has a different color from the incumbent pixel being compared. (Colors are stored as string attributes of object Pixel)

**First question:** *Should I use integers to represent my colors instead of string? Would this make the comparison function run significantly faster?*

In order to find the nearest pixel of different color, the program begins with all 8 adjacent pixels around the incumbent. If a nonMatch is not found, it then continues onto the next "degree", and in this fashion, it spirals out from the incumbent pixel until it hits a nonMatch. When found, the color of the nonMatch is saved as an attribute of incumbent. After I find the nonMatch for each of the Pixels, the data is re-inserted into the database

The program accomplishes what I want in the manner I've written it, but it is very very slow. After 24 hours, I am only about 3% through with execution.

**Question Two:** *Does my program behavior sound about right? Is this algorithm you would use if you had to accomplish this task?*

**Question Three:** *Would it be appropriate for me to use threads in order to finish execution of the program faster? How exactly does that work? (I am brand new to threads, but know a little of the syntax)*

**Question Four:** *Would it be more "intelligent" for my program to find the nonMatch for each pixel and insert it into the database immediately after finding it? (I'm making a guess that this would be good in multi-threading, because while one record is accessing the database (to insert), another record is accessing the array of pixels (shared global variable in program).*

**Question Five:** *If threading is a good idea, I'm guessing I would split the records up into more manageable chunks (i.e. quarters), and have each thread run the same functions for their specified number of records? Am I close at all?*

Please let me know if I can clarify or provide code samples, I just figured that this is more of a conceptual topic so do not want to overburden the post.

Comment: StackOverflow likes only one question per post.

Comment: Hi Christine, welcome to StackOverflow.  While your question is interesting, there are too many topics.  There are already countless questions about how to use threads as seen in the "Related" column to the right, so I'd suggest removing threading from this qustion and see if another question has an answer that suits you.

Comment: I stopped reading at *Should I use integers*.  Well, of course.  Huge difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Yes, integers compare much faster than strings. Additionally the y use much less memory

2.) I would adapt the algorithm in this way:

E.g.: #1: Let's say, for pixel(87,23) you found the nearest nonMatch to be (88,24) at degree=1 - you can immediately invert the relation and record, that the nearest nonMatch to (88,24) is (87,23). On degree=1 you finished 2 pixels with 1 search.

E.g. #2: Let's say, for pixel (17,18) you found the nearest nonMatch to be (17,20) at degree=2. You can immediately record, that all pixels, that border on both (16,19), (17,19) and (18,19) have the nearest noMatch (17,20) at degree=1, and that one of them is the nearest noMatch to (17,20). On degree=2 (or higher), you finished 5 pixels with 1 search.

3.) Using threads is a two-sided sword: You can do searches in parallel, but you need locking if you write to your array. So this depends on how many CPU cores you can throw at the problem. If this is 3 or more, threads will surely speed up the search.

4.) The results from 2.) make it necessary to mark a pixel as "done" in your array, as you might have finished up to 5 pixels with 1 search. I recommend you put those into a queue and use a dedicated thread to write the queue back into the database: MS Access can't handle concurrent updates, so a single database writer thread looks like a good idea.

5.) I recommend you NOT chunk up the array: You will run into problems with pixels on the edges of a chunk having their nearest nonMatch in a different chunk. Instead if you use e.g. 4 Threads, let them run 1.) From NW corner E, then S 2.) From SE Corner W, then N 3.) From NE Corner S, then W 4. From SW Corner N, then E

Comment: Hi @Eugen Rieck, thank you so much for your response. These tips are very helpful, and I'm excited to try them out tomorrow. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Using a integer would make it much faster
2. You can reuse the work you have done for previous pixel. Eg. If (a,b) is the nearest non-equal pixel of (x,y), it is likely that points around (x,y) might also have (a,b) as the nearest non-equal pixel
3. You can use different threads to work on different pixels instead of dividing searching for one pixel

IMHO, steps 1&2 should make your program much faster and you might not need multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd convert colour strings to Integers for speed, or even Color structures if you intend to display them on the screen.

Don't work directly with the database if you can avoid it.  Copy the necessary data out of the database into an array before you start, and copy your results back when you're finished.